# JHipster export-jdl problems

Tags: java, jhipster, jdl

I have a test project.
I have deleted by mistake jdl file.
Now, when i try to recreate jdl file from existing project using

```
jhipster export-jdl
```

i receive this message:

```
Using JHipster version installed locally in current project's node_modules
Executing jhipster:export-jdl
Options: 
Parsing entities from .jhipster dir...
The passed validation must be valid.
Errors: No value
events.js:183
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: ERROR! 
Error while parsing entities to JDL

at Environment.error (/home/igor/Development/IdeaProjects/StoVehiclesManagementSystems/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/environment.js:157:40)
at module.exports.error (/home/igor/Development/IdeaProjects/StoVehiclesManagementSystems/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/generator-base.js:2048:18)
at module.exports.generateJDLFromEntities (/home/igor/Development/IdeaProjects/StoVehiclesManagementSystems/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/generator-base-private.js:1002:18)
at module.exports.parseJson (/home/igor/Development/IdeaProjects/StoVehiclesManagementSystems/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/export-jdl/index.js:39:33)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/igor/Development/IdeaProjects/StoVehiclesManagementSystems/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/index.js:418:27)
at /home/igor/Development/IdeaProjects/StoVehiclesManagementSystems/node_modules/run-async/index.js:25:25
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at /home/igor/Development/IdeaProjects/StoVehiclesManagementSystems/node_modules/run-async/index.js:24:19
at self.env.runLoop.add.completed (/home/igor/Development/IdeaProjects/StoVehiclesManagementSystems/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/index.js:419:13)
at runCallback (timers.js:810:20)
```

Any idea what could be a problem?

Comment: It looks like an issue with the `validation` on one of the fields, but it's hard to tell

Comment: Try to run under node debugger: `node inspect node_modules/generator-jhipster/cli/jhipster.js export-jdl` then set a breakpoint before the error and inspect the variables, this way you should be able to understand what's wrong or maybe just exclude failing entity. See doc if you're not familiar with node debugger https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html